# How do I include Stripe library with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe payment https://stripe.com/ in my app. I need to include this library https://stripe.com/docs/libraries. I downloaded and installed it on Lib/site-packages.  I checked in IDLE and `import stripe` works. How do I include this in my app's folder?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just place the `stripe` directory from the library in your app's root directory.